# How to map using more 'accurate' DATUM than WGS84?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, datum, land-survey

WGS 84 is not very accurate as it is a compromise for the whole earth.

Assuming theoretically I'm surveying using very accurate IMU and very accurate GPS (in WGS 84 of course). I think I'll get a contradicting results:

While the GPS (as accurate as it is) will always throw me back to that 'compromise for the whole earth', the IMU on the other hand will very accurately draw a relative local 'true' map.

Am I correct here, that in such cases I need to convert the GPS's WGS84 coordinates into some more accurate DATUM dedicated for the region I'm in (ITRF?), in order to align IMU's relative map to some global frame? Because the global frame of that more proper DATUM to my region is closer to the local map the IMU's outputed rather than the rough estimation of the regular WGS 84?

EDIT:

The black line is the result of the IMU.

The blue line is WGS84

The green line is GDA2020 (assuming it's Australia).

coord 1 blue != coord 1 green

coord 1 blue is what I get from the GPS

coord 1 green since it's GDA2020 is more acculturate represents reality (the black line).

Am I correct here?
[image]

Comment: Transforming does not lead to more accurate positions, but makes these comparable to local measures. A local datum is more accurate for survey, because survey measurements highly depend on the local geoid undulation.

Comment: @AndreasMüller but "but makes these comparable to local measures" this is what I want, not? Since "Transforming does not lead to more accurate positions" is basically to say that the accuracy limited to the accuracy of the GPS - fine, I assume DGPS, RTK etc. so I fine with the accuracy. Am my understanding here correct?

Comment: First: I do not provide an answer here, because this materia is really complex and I am really not an expert in geodesy. Second: When i say transform, i mean transforming between datums and those are invertable. So it does not matter which part you want to transform. The target system should be the same as that of other data sets you may use. Personally I think it is important to choose and trust the correct transformation (...software). Local agencies (eg. in Europe) spend much effort into these transformations.

Answer (score 1):

> *Assuming theoretically I'm surveying using very accurate IMU and very accurate GPS (in WGS 84 of course). I think I'll get a contradicting
>   results.*

A good IMU can only give good relative measurements. No doubt it can tell you accurately the headings and distances traveled, but alas these values are "floating" so long as their initial position on earth is unspecified. You can choose to specify it in the WGS84 (G1762) reference frame, or ITRF 2008 reference frame, or your country's ordinance reference frame(s).

For our discussion here, it helps if you understand that a *position* is meaningless if it does not have a reference frame. Eg, *"East 102 deg, North 4 deg"* is meaningless, but "*"East 102 deg, North 4 deg in WGS84 (G1762)"* is not.

If you specify your initial position in the WGS84 (G1762) reference frame, then all the positions derived from your IMU measurements will also be in the WGS84 (G1762) reference frame. Likewise, the error-margin of your initial position determines the error-margins of all the positions derived from your IMU measurements. For example, if your initial position has an error of plus/minus 25 meter radius, then so would all the positions derived from the traveled headings/distances.

To clarify, the phrase *"very accurate GPS (in WGS 84)"* is flawed because it is unclear if you meant the WGS84 reference frame itself, or the equipment you had used to obtain the position, or something else.

Hence, no - you should never get any contradicting results because the premises on which your question were drawn were fundamentally incorrect in the first place. You need position to give context to your relative IMU measurements.

> *Am I correct here, that in such cases I need to convert the GPS's
>   WGS84 coordinates into some more accurate DATUM dedicated for the
>   region I'm in (ITRF?), in order to align IMU's relative map to some
>   global frame? Because the global frame of that more proper DATUM to my
>   region is closer to the local map the IMU's outputed rather than the
>   rough estimation of the regular WGS 84?*

WGS84 (G1762) is a global frame and it is the latest WGS84 reference frame. Its geocentre coincides with the geocentre of ITRF 2008 (another global frame) within 10 centimeters. Both of them adopted the IERS Reference Pole as their rotation axis, and both has the same Reference Meridian (Longitude 0). In this age of satellite positioning, a country's ordinance reference frame would always be referenced against one of the (later) WGS84 or ITRF reference frame, and the authority would publish the necessary parameters to go from the ordinance reference frame to WGS84 or ITRF.

Hence, if your initial position (in whatever reference frame) has a wide error margin, transforming or converting it to any other reference frame will not increase/improve its accuracy, as the same amount of error is carried over.

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. I'll give an example: When mapping Australia I can use GPS coordinates (WGS84), and I'm using the best RTK so I have "0" error. BUT, since we all know that for Australia GDA2020 is the more accurate DATUM, am I must convert my GPS coordinates into GDA2020 in order for the survey to be more accurate?

Comment: @michael: For me to understand what you are trying to ask please share here (1) how did you get your "GPS coordinates", ie what brand/model of device/equipment did you use? And, (2) what RTK did you use, ie software, service, etc?

Comment: Why this is important? It's a theoretical question. I have WGS84 coordinates 100% true and accurate (from my GPS) & I have accurate IMU represent local 100% accurate reality in some area. But if it's Australia, all I read out was "WGS84 not good, GDA2020 is good". So if I want to align "local 100% accurate reality (from the IMU)", it seems for me that the WGS84 frame is by definition not accurate for my area, so I need somehow take the GPS readings that by definition are WGS84 and convert them into GDA2020?

Comment: It is important because I am trying to ascertain the causes of your confusion - and attempting to help you clear them. The more information you provide, the easier it would be. I also do not know which literature you had read that lead you to the conclusion/opinion that WGS84 is bad. Here is a point for your consideration - without "WGS84", GDA2020 would not had been successfully "realized". Surveyors usually don't work with WGS84 (G1762) mainly because it is a 4D datum from the perspective of GDA2020.

Comment: I'll add a picture in the question

Comment: The blue and green line were supposed to represent the curvature of the earth or ellipsoid of reference datums (ie WGS84 vs GDA2020)?

Comment: The true curvature of the earth is the Black - only the accurate IMU can draw it... Blue & Green represent different "DATUMs" (for the sake of simplicity ellipsoid is encapsulated under "DATUM" since the frame is also relevant etc.). The Green one represents something that more accurately (compared to Blue) represents the truth which is the Black.